# Capturing frame using AVCaptureVideoDataOutPut

Tags: iphone, video-capture, avcapturesession

hello friends.

I am a korean student.

and I am making augment reality iPhone app with Xcode 4.3

so I need to capture frame from camera.

then I searched "how to capture from camera"

and I finally found that using AVCaptureVideoDataOutPut is only possible to capture frame from camera..

but I don't know how to use AVCaptureVideoDataOutPut to capture frame from camera.

also I have not found exactly source code using AVCaptureVideoDataOutPut.

so I can't make argument reality app anymore.

so I really want to see or get source code which is code

using AVCaptureVideoDataOutPut to capture frame from camera in IOS 5.x not IOS 4.x

please help me.

Comment: - - pure poetry!

Answer (score 4):

First, see the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html). Particularly read the "Media Capture" section.

You will then want to look at the [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code. It covers much of what you're looking for.